# On active userform perform function and display function value as caption

Tags: excel, userform, vba

**Background:**

I am working on a userform to perform several calculations so that I can lock the formulas in a module (intentionally not using protect sheet and doing this in the spreadsheet).  I have listed a Label in the appropriate location and am intending to use userform.Show vbModeless so that I can get the functions to display information as is written into text boxes.

---

**Issue:**

In trying to compile, I am getting a Run-time error 13: Type Mismatch on my function for trying to take the value of the TextBox (the line in the code with *a = calcs.Controls("TextBox11").Value*).

---

**Question:**

I am not seeing what is mismatched, as I'm calling the controls indirectly using Controls("").  Anyone seeing where I may have F'd up?

Additionally, is this a pipedream to have a function update on the userform as values are input to text boxes on the same userform?

---

**Code in Question:**

The name of my userform is *calcs*.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub button_show()
    calcs.Show vbModeless
    calcs.Controls("Label95").Caption = calc1() 
End Sub

Private Function calc1() As Double
    Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double, d As Double, e As Double
    a = calcs.Controls("TextBox11").Value 'FLAG
    b = calcs.Controls("TextBox1").Value
    c = calcs.Controls("TextBox2").Value
    d = calcs.Controls("TextBox3").Value
    e = calcs.Controls("TextBox4").Value 
    calc1 = (a * b * d * 1000) / (1000 * c * e * 1)
End Function
```

Comment: If TextBox11 is empty or contains any other value that cannot be converted to a double you will get that error, is that the case? If not what is its value?

Comment: You can't expect the **Text**Box value (cf. its `.Text` property) to harmonize with a **Double** type declaration, so an Error 13 will be inevitable: either same type or convert the control value.

Comment: @AlexK. is empty to start.  Should I initialize it with a value of 0?

Comment: @T.M. when you say "convert the control value," what does that entail?

Comment: You could, but if a user entered "WAFFLES" you would get the same error as whatever you assign to a double variable must be convertible to a double.  Consider creating a helper function that verifies the value (with isnumeric() for example)

Comment: @AlexK. copy; thanks for the input.  will test and see if that resolves

Comment: @AlexK. that resolved the mistmatch error.  thanks

Comment: @Cyril - the TextBox string value could be converted to a number type e.g. via `a = Val(Me.TextBox2.value)` just to demonstrate the simplest way.

Comment: @T.M. badass; i forgot about Val() as i was going through this... thank you!